# Display expand/collapse button depending on div height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a Div that, if it is higher than 68px, I want it to hide the rest of the content and to appear an option to expand it.

The problem is that I dont know how to detect when the div is higher than 68px. Especially because the div is responsive.

I have tried to count characters with PHP and depending on the number of characters display the expand button. But this technique is very unprecise because some characters are wider than others.

This is the website where I am trying to solve this problem: http://www.metagame.gg/champions/azir#comp

As you can appreciate, it is responsive, so this makes the problem harder. The middle box "Weak Against" doesnt need to be expanded.

Here is a picture: [image: Image of the problem to solve]

I am trying to find a solution to this using JavaScript / CSS / HTML

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery:

```js
jQuery('.expandClicker').each(function(){
  if (jQuery(this).parent().height() < 68) {
    jQuery(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

I tried it out on your page and seemed to work fine.

You could also replace the `fadeOut();` with:

```
jQuery(this).css({'display':'none'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using jQuery to look at the width attribute of the css class.

**With regard to the divs being responsive:**

Within your css, the width of the box when on a smaller screen (max-width: 980px) is 100%, the width of the box when the screen > 1300px wide is 32.8%. Thus you can write a script that would look at the width property and act accordingly, that being if the width is 32.8% then check the height and apply the logic for if the height is greater than desired ([see article here](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries)).

**With regard to finding the height:**

Applying the height is as others have said, a case of looking at the height property of the div. If it is larger than your desired max height, then apply the desired css.

**With regard to the read more**:

take a look at this example:

What it is essentially doing is what you were trying to do in PHP, it looks at the character count and says if the read more has yet to be clicked, then split the text after the last maximum character, and then put the rest of the text in a hidden span.

If read more is pressed, then display all of the text inside of the hidden span alongside the already displayed text.

http://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA/

here is the code from that codepen:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Read More/Less Toggle Example</title>
    <style>
    .morecontent span {
        display: none;
    }
    .morelink {
       display: block;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <div class="more">
      Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";


    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

*First of all, I don't recommend using a table with just a single row and a single column for each cell as seen in your screenshot.*

I would recommend wrapping your text with an additional div (inner wrapper) and using max-width on your outer wrapper. Via JS you can compare if the inner wrappers height is greater than the outer wrappers (max-)height. If positive add a class to your outer-wrapper. This class triggers the visibility of your "read more" link.

*I wont provide a jsFiddle or any code, because you did not provide any source code to work on. And I don't want to re-create your page in jsFiddle using developer tools on your linked page.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me some insight of why you dont recommend the use of a table in this case? I agree with you (This was created a year ago when I was a very newbie developer) but I would love to know if there is any particular downside.

Comment: What profit do you gain, using a new table for each cell, when you can either use a single table with all the three cells (which could be your outer wrapper) or don't use a table at all.
You should only use tables for actually displaying table data. Everything else is just bad practice.
       
I would use a grid system instead (like bootstrap), and use it's predefined easy responsive features.